# K-means, bag of word, Word embedded text classification CSV file and retrieve data associated

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, supervised-learning

I have two tasks to do.

1)I have to extract the headers of any CVS file containing invoices data.
In specific: invoice number, address, location, physical good. 
I have been asked to create a text classifier for this task, therefore the classifier will go over any CVS file and identify those 4 headers.

2)After the classifier identifies the 4 words I have to find the attach the data of that column and create a class.

I researched the matter and the three methodologies that I thought were must be appropriated are: 
1)bad of words
2)word embedded
3)K-means clustering

Bag of words can identify the word but it does not give me the location of the word itself to go and grab the column and create the class.

Word embedded is over complicated for this task, I believe, and even if give me the position of the word in the file is too time-consuming for this

K-means seems simple and effective it tells me where the word is.

My question before I start coding

did I miss something. Is my reasoning correct?
And most important the second question 
Once the position of the word is identified in the CSV file how I translate that into coding so I can attach the data in that column

Comment: You are looking for an appropriate way to find specific column names in any csv header and their column *numbers*? The header being the first line of the csv?

Comment: The short answer is yes. I am looking to grab some particular header with some particular name and then when I know is there grab the data not necessarily numbers. Could be numbers or could be strings.
They ask me to do this with an ML text classifier but I think is overdoing.

Comment: I ask anyway to do the text classifier. When do I know the position of the word using means how can I attach the data that is in the column?

Comment: The columns of a row/line of a csv file should be delineated by something, usually a comma but could be a tab.  If you split a string on that delimiter you will get a list with each column value as an item in the list - e.g. `[1,2,3,4,5]` and if you know the column index for your names you can get those values with ther index. Say you want columns zero and two --> `split_line[0]` and `split_line[2]`.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply:

- look at the first line of the file (the header);

  - [filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) out the column names you are looking for, use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) so the result will contain the column indices
  - retrieve the column indices from the filtered result
- iterate over the rest of the file;

  - use those indices to extract the specific columns' data from each line/row

    - put that data in a container for use later (maybe use a list)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
Is what I will do. 
But since this is for a task I have been asked to create a text classifier.
How I would do when I know the position of the word from the k-means classifier to attach the column of date.

Comment: Do you think I can do the same if instead of csv file there is json file?
What I am trying to say can I do the same procedure you describe here with a json file?
Thank you for your kindness anyway

Comment: I don't have any experience using text classifiers but from what little I know I'm having a hard time seeing/understanding how that would even be useful for examining the header of a csv file to determine the indices of the columns of interest.  It is certainly possible to parse a json file to extract needed/wanted information but the details of the process would depend on the structure of the json - you would have to have prior knowledge of the structure.  I don't know enough about nlp and text classification to know whether that could be used to extract info from a json string.